# GameObject.Find can't find the object after i changed its name

Tags: unity, c#

I created this script to create a group of plane meshes with offset between them in my game scene, then change their names and give an ID to every one of them:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class creatingobjectslist : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject TargetPrefab;

    void Start () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Instantiate(TargetPrefab, new Vector3(i * 1.5f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            TargetPrefab.name = "Ben" +i;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created this script and attached it to another object to move my object to one of the objects that was created with the `creatingobjectslist` script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MoveCubeTogrid : MonoBehaviour {
    UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start () {
        agent = GetComponent< UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent >();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
                    //agent.destination = hit.point;
                    agent.destination = GameObject.Find("Ben0").transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after running that I get this error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: [There's a cautionary tale I like to pass along when folks are looking up GameObjects by name](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784). There's almost always a way that's as simple, and more reliable / easier to debug. In this case, you already have a script creating each object in order - why not have it store those objects in a collection that other scripts can reference by index, so you don't need to search the whole scene for particular names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You're renaming the prefab, not the clone:

```
TargetPrefab.name = "Ben" +i;
```

As such, the first one has `OriginalName (clone)` for a name, the second one is called `Ben0 (clone)`, then `Ben1 (clone)` and so on.

If you had checked your scene hierarchy at runtime you would have noticed this.